# How To Add a Dll TO MFC Application in visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, mfc

I have an MFC GUI application project in Visual studio 2010.

I want to get communication with a mini circuit signal generator device. The device has a DLL file named `mcl_gen64.dll`.

I want to use functions of that DLL in my code but I don't have any idea how to do this: Any idea please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://ww2.minicircuits.com/softwaredownload/Quick%20Setup%20Guide.pdf

```
typedef int (__stdcall *ConnectByAddressPtr)(short Addr); 

ConnectByAddressPtr ConnectByAddress = NULL;
HMODULE hLib = LoadLibrary(_T("mcl_gen64.dll"));
if (hLib)
    ConnectByAddress = 
(ConnectByAddressPtr)GetProcAddress(hLib,"ConnectByAddress");
if (ConnectByAddress)
    ConnectByAddress(0x01)
```

The dll should exist in your executable folder. Or if you debug it in VS, in your project's folder as well. Mind the "__stdcall" notation when defining the function pointer.

Comment: Hi after a long time. sorry cuz i was not able to check your answers. the doc you sent me, helped me alot. finally i added dll to my code and visual studio created .h files for me and now i can use the functions like ConnectByAddress and ...

Comment: But still there is a problem. when i run the code, nothing happen. i mean it seems that i am not sending any data on the usb port. is it being done automatically or shall i do something to connect to the usb port?

Comment: now i connect the device to pc usb port and i monitor the port by a software but when i execute for example "Connect" function, ino data is being transfered

Comment: I'm not familiar with this device and it's SDK. I have to test it thoroughly in order to answer you, if you need to? You might need to read the documentation and check the examples.

Comment: I have read the documents which i have found in internet. i think the problem is in opening USB port. i dont know if it opens automatically or not

Comment: Cannot help you without testing it myself.

Comment: Ok, thank you. you helped me alot in this case. i will try to fix the problem. i'll inform you if it gets fixed. thank you so much for your kindly help